$T:\ell^{\infty}\rightarrow L^{p}$ is continuous (norm-to-norm), is it weak*-to-weak continuous?
Given norm-to-norm continuous map $T:\ell^{\infty}\rightarrow L^{p}$, $p\geq
1$. Does norm-to-norm continuous imply weak*-to-weak continuous?
I have learnt that: if $T$ is norm-norm continuous then it is weak-weak
continuous, what about weak*-to-weak continuous?
The bot mention A linear map $S:Y^*\to X^*$ is weak$^*$ continuous if and only if $S=T^*$ for some $T\in B(X,Y)$, I am a green hand, but I think weak* continuous is weak* -to-norm continuous, not weak*-to-weak continuous.

Actually, in the second linked question, weak$^\ast$ continuous means weak$^\ast$-to-weak$^\ast$ continuous, not weak$^\ast$-to-norm continuous.

Write $X = l^\infty$ and $Y=L_p$.  We will use:  $X$ is a dual space but not reflexive, and $Y \ne \{0\}$.
Since $X$ is not reflexive, there is a bounded linear functional $\phi$ on $X$ that is not weak* continuous.  Choose a nonzero vector $u \in Y$.  Define rank-one operator
$T : X \to Y$ by
$$
T(x) = \phi(x) u,\quad x \in X .
$$
Then $T$ is norm-norm continuous, but not weak*-weak continuous.
